# Scrapy - importing spider as a module

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to deploy a spider from within a `python` script.

this is my folder stucture:

```
scraping.py
blogs/
     __init_.py
     blogs/
     scrapy.cfg
          __init_.py
          items.py
          settings.py
          spiders/
                 __init__.py
                 spider_blog.py
```

this is the test `scraping.py` snippet (it belongs to a `class`):

```
def spider_blog(self):

    parse()
```

and this is what I have in `spider_blog.py`:

```
class PitchforkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pitchfork_reissues"
    allowed_domains = ["pitchfork.com"]
    #creates objects for each URL listed here
    start_urls = [
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=1",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=2",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=3",
    ]


    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="album-artist"]'):
            item = PitchforkItem()
            item['artist'] = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="artist-list"]/li/text()').extract()
            item['reissue'] = sel.xpath('//h2[@class="title"]/text()').extract()

        yield item
```

how is the proper syntax for me to import `parse()` from `spider_blog.py` as a `module` into `scraping.py`?

Comment: try creating an `__init__.py` file into `spiders/` folder

Comment: @eLRuLL it has `__init__.py` already, and so has the first `child`folder. But do you know the correct syntax? I tried `from blogs.blogs.spiders import *`, but I get `ImportError: No module named blogs.blogs.spiders`

Comment: put `scraping.py` inside the first `blogs/` folder, so you are inside the same project, and just import `from blogs.spiders ...` normally